# How to get rid of archer queen when attacking?

Tags: clash-of-clans

When attacking with giants or hogs, they always get destroyed quickly by the archer queen. If the queen is in the middle of the base, she can't be loured out. Otherwise I'd take care of her similar to Clan Castle troops. I'm TH 8.

A problem is hogs can jump over walls, but the troops that would attack the queen generally don't (e.g. wizard, archer, barbarian, p.e.k.k.a, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When attacking a base with an Archer Queen, you need to make sure to take other units besides your tanks to take out the queen. If you are taking Giants, generally you want take some wizards or a pekka to come behind them and clear out the buildings as the Giants are tanking for them. You can use a poison spell to slow the attack speed of the Archer Queen, and a heal spell to keep your Giants alive till the other troops can kill the queen. I generally don't have much trouble with the queen when using Giants.

For hogs, you rarely want to use full hogs against a th9+. If you are wanting to use hogs, you should look to be using gohowi (golems, wizards , hogs) or similar type attack strategy. Send in the golem and wizards with earthquake spells, a jump spell, or some wall breakers to get into the middle of the base and take out the queen. The hogs are then used to take out point defenses while your golems are tanking the damage. Consider looking at OneHive Raids YouTube channel for attack strategy tutorials.

Comment: So I know to bring in other troops to take out the archer queen, but they just got distracted by the line of elixer pumps infront of the defense (archer towers, morters) and they got squashed. Should you send in the giants/hogs to take out the defense near the archer queen, and then send the wizards/pekkas behind them? Should you wait for the giants/hogs to have actually destroyed the defense near the archer queen or should you deploy them right behind the giants/hogs? The problem is even more difficult as hogs can jump over walls and wiz/pekka can't.

Comment: @Celeritas I generally send a few Giants near the side I'm attacking, then use some wizards to create a funnel. I don't use pekkas with hogs. I use gohowi. Pekkas will generally follow a similar path to Giants if you create a good funnel.

Comment: What do you mean "funnel"?

Comment: @Celeritas that is a pretty long thing to describe, maybe post another question asking what funneling means in the context of CoC and I can answer it there as it would probably help quite a few people.

Comment: Done https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/270118/what-is-funneling

Comment: @Celeritas working on an in-depth explanation.

Comment: Attacking a TH9 base as a TH8 is *very* difficult unless the TH9 base is really rushed. Considering the troop upgrade levels a TH8 base can hit, I almost always used GOWIPE. I then either tried to avoid the Queen, or lure the clan castle into her general direction so I could include her in the poison spells.

Comment: @Ellesedil yea, attacking a th level above you is almost always  pretty difficult. Dragons or gowipes tend to be the best for th8 attacking a th9, though once a th9 gets close to max, a dragon attack will have a very hard time of succeeding