# How can I effectively use the Baby Dragon?

Tags: clash-of-clans

The newish Baby Dragon has a unique role compared to other flying units, as it has a mechanic which enrages them when they are separated from other flying units. How can I effectively use baby dragons to take advantage of this mechanic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The baby dragon is generally best if by themselves in the air, but while they have much more damage when enraged, being grouped together does not make them necessarily weak. They have a little of half the health of a regular dragon, about half the damage per second when not enraged, and take up half the housing cost. This means that if you were to take two baby dragons instead of a regular dragon, you would have a similar amount of damage, which a little bit more health for the same housing cost, with the added benefit of them becoming enraged as they split and gaining 2x damage per second. Thus they can be used pretty effectively is mass.

Another use for them, which I use frequently, is to use them to create a [funnel](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/270122/127901). A lot of people tend to use a few wizards to funnel in their troops, however a level 2 baby dragon has about 3 times the combined health of three level 5 wizards though somewhat less damage per second. This extra health, as well as being air units will allow them to create funnels in places where wizards will get quickly picked off by defenses, and using one on each side of the funnel will guarantee that they will be enraged and they will be able to create the funnel pretty quickly.

One other use for baby dragons is to use them as cleanup troops. Their ability to fly allows them to bypass walls, so they will not get hung up attacking walls to get to those last buildings. If your main force consists of ground troops, then your baby dragons will most likely be alone in the air, and thus in a constant state of enragement making it so they are essentially a regular dragon in terms of damage, and thus can quickly burn their way through the remainder of a base.

While, they are great at attacking, they can also be effective defending in a clan castle. If you combine them with a regular dragon, their combined splash damage and health can make it tough for an attacker to deal with. Alternatively, you can pair a baby dragon with some ground troops, such as max giants, valkyries, or witches, which can distract the attacking troops for a short time, while the enraged baby dragon can pump out pretty significant splash damage on anything nearby.

Also, as  @Ellesedil pointed out; another benefit to using baby dragons vs normal dragons is that an air seeking mine will waste a lot of it's damage when it targets a baby dragon. A regular dragon with full HP can survive an air seeking mine, but just about anything that can attack air units will quickly finish it off. Dragons that have been damaged previously almost always succumb to air seeking mines. Since baby dragons distributes that health and damage across more targets, the damage an air seeking mine does is less drastic.

Comment: Another benefit to using baby dragons vs normal dragons is that an air seeking mine will waste a lot of it's damage when it targets a baby dragon. A regular dragon with full HP *can* survive an air seeking mine, but just about anything that can attack air units will quickly finish it off. Dragons that have been damaged previously almost always succumb to air seeking mines. Since baby dragons distributes that health and damage across more targets, the damage an air seeking mine does is less drastic.

Comment: @Ellesedil that is a great point. Mind if I edit it into my answer (with attribution)?

Comment: Go for it. If a comment improves an answer, include it  :p

Comment: @Ellesedil some people might get upset if I use a large excerpt like that, so best to ask first.