# Can we use funneling while using GOwipe?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I really need to know since I have started using **GOwipe** and heard about **funneling** that can we combine the GOwipe and funneling and can funnel troops like P.E.K.K.A using Golem in place of Gaints? Please help me if someone know. Thanks!

Comment: related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/270118/what-is-funneling/270122#270122

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funneling is sometimes simple, and other times complicated.

If you encounter a base with straight walls and less intersection of walls. That is simple to funnel.

If the base has lot of (non-defence)buildings outside then that particular side is hard to funnel.

---

Method (**how to do it**)

- Place your tanking troops(giant,golem,lava) first on one side. Wait until all defences are locked on those tanks. Then deploy funneling troops(wizards,baby dragons,archers).
- Next step is to wait another few seconds and then deploy wall breakers in groups of 2. So it goes like this TAP TAP .... TAP TAP .. and so on. Here waiting is a key because your wizards are clearing outside buildings and thus when it is clean, wallbreakers are more likely to target to centre.
- Once the way to centre is open then you can drop pekkas. Drop pekks carefully because if you misplaced it then there is high chance that they will go merry-go-round the base. Pekka will target nearest building when deployed so drop it in such a way that it will go inside the base.

Thats the method called funneling.
(PS. Hopefully that was comprehensive)

Comment: Assuming u have maximum obtainable level of wall breakers in your current townhall level

Comment: thanx for your help in this ques. well are you indian? @Fennekin

Comment: @microbuster Yes, but why do you ask?

Comment: I was just guessing. well I have three ques related to this.

Comment: 1. can I use earthquake spell to break those walls? 2. can I use archers instead of wizards? 3. In what other way can I combine them? [If you are not supporting archers because I dont want to waste my all elixire only in wizard] @Fennekin

Comment: 1 - You can ! ; 2 - yes but they are only effective when used skillfully.(in waves) ; 3 - you can add few valks. 1 or 2 balloons and minions.