# How to funnel Valkyries into the base core?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I tried using valkyries  with giants and hogs and wizards and my strategy is usually to remove some obstacles in front of wall using archers and wiz and then drop giants so they go to the wall directly where I want them to, using wall breakers I create an opening and giants goes in but now if I drop valks in front of that opening they do not go in!! Instead they start circling around base and die without gaining any useful resources? How can I get them in with giants. My king and queen are enough to circle around.

Comment: I have already written post http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/278137/can-we-use-funneling-while-using-gowipe/278308#278308

Answer (score 1):

**Army and Spell Composition**

2 Jump spells, 2 Rage spells, a heal spell, an earthquake spell, 14 Giants, 8 wizards, 14 Valkyries, and 24 archers.

**Strategy**

Put a single archer to clear out any undefended buildings around the edges possible, one archer per building. Use 1 or 2 giants on either side of the target rush location. Use a wizard to clear out 2 buildings to the left of the left giant, and 2 to the right of the right giant, also, one per building between them. Put a jump as effectively as possible ((Don't worry if you fail once or twice, the game does that on its' own, and it takes some practice!)) over the target walls. Flood with the rest of your giants. After about 3-5 seconds, place down all but 2 of your Valkyries, and a rage spell just closer to the core than you placed the jump spell. If there is clan castle troops, Good! The Valkyries will head straight to them. Don't be afraid to use your second jump spell to get there! If you didn't use your second jump spell yet, however, place it so it slightly overlaps the first jump spell, assuming a pocket-style village. If at any time, there is a lot of splash defenses hitting, put down your heal spell so it covers the majority, if not all of your giants and Valkyries. Throw your king and queen in right behind your Valkyries. They'll help more in the core than in the cleanup, and don't use their abilities until they are being targeted by late level-2 inferno tower heat, or until they are flashing orange on their health bar. I will likely be about 20-45 seconds in.

This is all assuming you are trophy pushing, and can expend troops on raids like this often. If that is indeed, or even halfway the case, I suggest replacing your giants with 2 Golems, 2 Valkyries, and 4 archers. Or a wizard, your choice entirely.

This will nearly always guarantee a 2-star attack, however, do NOT under ANY circumstances attack a village with the inferno towers a wall and a square away from the core buildings, as they will chew though your troops, and you'll end up with a flat 49.

Thank supercell for not adding aggro in the last one!

Answer (score 1):

**This could be a good strategy:**

**Troops and spells used:**

15 valkyries, 10 to 15 giants, 20 archers or 10 wizards, 4 to 6 wall breakers (you can also use [GOwipe](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=gowipe), remove some wizards and add valkyries), 1 rage spell, 1 heal spell and rest you could use earthquake or lighting spells (max).

**How to use**

1. drop your giants to those defences which are at the outside so that they are **busy** in killing those **tanking troops.**
2. In this time use archers or wizards to use them in [funelling](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/270118/what-is-funneling).
3. Then send in the wall breakers to blow those walls in groups of two.
4. Drop in the rage spells at the entrance. (Make sure that the giants are busy in their work).
5. Drop in the valkyries into the holes.
6. If you like you can use the heal spell to send them in with no problem.
7. Crack every thing which comes in your way with the earthquake and lighting spells.

**And that is how you can use this method to funnel you valkyries.**

Answer (score 0):

TH9

20 valk, 12 wizards, and 6 Wallbreakers, 2 heal 2 rage 1 haste/skeleton.

METHOD 1: First I use the King to tank for 3 wizards and 6 wallbreaks to take out the circle of importance. Send one valk in to make sure it does go in, then go all out, and use wizards for extra damage, rage works really well for 2 star in Master->Champion

METHOD 2: If there is a queen or king or warden 3 tiles away from the wall, send all of your valks in. They get attracted by the hero. You might want to drop a rage/haste to make sure the king doesn't get out of the wall before the valks get in

Answer (score -2):

1 Golem(one in cc), 9 valks, 10 wiz, 1 hog, 4 wall brakers, 1 Jump, 2 Heal, 2 rage

Strategy: Place both golems and then put all wall brakers to make an opening, put wizards to take out the troops around the base. Then put heroes and valks they should go in the hole once they have taken everything around the center put a jump spell so they can enter the center.( Use the hog to take out the cc troops.) You can use the spells as you like I would focus mainly in the valks but you can do what makes you the most comfortable.

Comment: Hopefully it works